# Laravel: load custom class from new custom directory

Tags: laravel-4

I have currently added a new folder to my app directory for all my 'libraries'. I keep recieving an error that the class is not found, this is what I do:

I have added it to the composer.json file in the autoload value:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/services",
        "app/facades",
        "app/libraries" --> here
    ]
},
```

Added it to my global.php file in the classloader:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/libraries', --> here

));
```

Created an alias for it in app.php:

```
'aliases' => array(

    'App'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Session'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    ...
    'SimpleImage'       => 'App\Libraries\abeautifulsite\SimpleImage', --> here

),
```

And called the class in my controller:

```
$img = new SimpleImage($file);
```

The error I keep receiving is that the class is not found. What am I missing?

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Class 'App\Libraries\abeautifulsite\SimpleImage' not found
```

(PS. I did composer dump-autoload in terminal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to add a custom folder in your Laravel project is using `PSR-4`.

First of all create your custom directory in `/app`, for example:

```
/app/YourName/libraries
```

now open `composer.json` and just after the `autoload -> classmap` add the `psr-4` structure:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/services",
        "app/facades"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "YourName\\": "app/YourName"
    }
},
```

Note that I **removed** your `/app/libraries` row, then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

In this way all the folders you will add in **YourName** folder will be loaded.

For example:

```
app/ChristianGiupponi/libraries
```

and

```
"psr-4": {
    "ChristianGiupponi\\": "app/ChristianGiupponi"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, after more than 4 hours of searching the class is recognized and my custom library is working! Hope this will spare me time in te future.