# Laravel 5.4 application can't load custom class in custom directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522186/7956165) and some other but couldn't get this work.

I have custom directory in `App` -> `libraries` which holds custom php class. In composer.json I've added it in psr-4 section

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "libraries\\": "app/libraries"

    }
},
```

In the controller in which I want to use the class `App\Http\Controller\OrderController.php` I've added this

```
use App\libraries\API; // on top of the page


class OrderController extends BaseController
{
    public function orderSubmit()
    {
           // some code 
        API::convertUSDToEUR($product['price']);
    }
}
```

The error

> FatalThrowableError Class 'App\libraries\API' not found

I've do `composer dump-autoload` too

Comment: Tried `use libraries\API;` ?

Comment: Yes, and only `use API;`, and tried `libraries\API::convertUSDToEUR($product['price']);`

Comment: I think this may be a namespacing issue, have you tried: `namespace App\Libraries;` then `use API;`

Comment: Where to put this namespace `namespace App\Libraries;`? Because in the controller where I want to use it I already have `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: BTW in views I don't have this problem. If I do `{{ API::convertUSDToEUR($product['price']) }}` It's working. But when I trying to call in controller got the error above

Comment: `namespace App; use Http\BaseController; use libraries\API;`

Comment: @T.Salvin this return me `BaseController not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is not defined in current namespace. You should be able to call it like `new \API(...)` or like this.

```
use API; 


class OrderController extends BaseController
{
    public function orderSubmit()
    {
           // some code 
        $convert = new API;
        $convert->convertUSDToEUR($product['price']);
    }
}
```

Edit: This declaration in composer.json will work too. Laravel it will load everything in `autoload`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/libraries"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"

    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer will try now

Comment: Yes, it's working! I've been tried to add `use API;` but didn't tried to create `new API;`..